# How to distinguish token from a liquidity pool?

Tags: web3js, erc-20, abi

Let's take two addresses:

- [Pancake LPs](https://bscscan.com/address/0x8774ecc7A9E223092c672180Ca7692b03a53559D#readContract)
- [ElonGate](https://bscscan.com/address/0x2A9718defF471f3Bb91FA0ECEAB14154F150a385#readContract)

The first one is a liquidity pool that implements `IPancakePair` interface and the second one is a `IERC20` token.

Short of inspecting the name, how can I differentiate the two programmatically?

I have [abi](/questions/tagged/abi) for `IPancakePair` and `IERC20`.

Comment: Why do you want to differentiate them? Usually LP are ERC20. There's no EIP standard for LP, any possible difference is at most a weak one. It should be trivial to write an LP that doesn't have any difference from a regular ERC20 token.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to check if code implements interface of `PancakePair` or `IERC20`.

The way to do is that you need to pull the code using [web3js](/questions/tagged/web3js) and then check if it contains signature of every method in the interface, e.g.

```js
const matchSignature = (
  web3: Web3Type,
  code: string,
  abi: $ReadOnlyArray<Object>,
) => {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    abi,
  );

  return contract.options.jsonInterface.every((token) => {
    return !token.signature || code.includes(token.signature.slice(2));
  });
};
```